# How to make eslint indentation the same as vscode auto-format indentation?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

My `vscode` auto formats my code when I save a file but, after running `eslint --quiet --fix --ext .js,.ts,.tsx,.jsx .` I get a lot of indentation changes in my files. Here's an example:

```
// vscode auto format on save
await myFunction(
  var1, {
  prop1: 'abc'
  prop2: 'xyz'   
} ) 

// eslint fix
await myFunction(
  var1, {
    prop: 'abc'
    ... etc   
  } )
```

Note that `eslint` adds an extra indent on object props.

Here's my `.eslintrc.js` indentation settings:

```
'indent': [ 'error', 2, { 'SwitchCase': 1 } ]
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `vscode` auto formats your files on save so you'll not have problems with indentation (unless you use `ctrl + k, s` wich saves without formatting), in this case you can just disable `eslint` indentation rule so `eslint` will not do these changes anymore. Just change your rule to:

```
'indent': 'off'
```

Hope this helps :)